How to not see through mesh in RetopoFlow?
I'm using Blender 4.2 and RetopoFlow 3.4.3. When I am retopologizing, the source mesh or the high polygon mesh and the retopologized mesh are both transparent. Here is a picture of what I mean.

Is there anyway to fix this?

That's a fairly expensive commercial addon so unless anyone here has bought it we can't really help. Assuming you aren't in x-ray or wireframe view you should you ask the author.

Not possible to answer since we don't have the addon as John has pointed out. Contact the author.
